# Adding Background images in ADT

Tags: eclipse, adt

I really need help (am a newbie to ADT/Eclipse), I set up a back ground image by placing the image first in the res/drawable folder and then proceeded to place it in my application usind the:
android:background = "@drawable/image" 
I then proceeded to change the layout to "scrollview"
The image appeared in the Graphical layout but after a while, ADT showed me an error saying:
(Where the error is at where "R" is written e.g. setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
the error reads "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I would kindly appreciate if anyone helps :D